# button is not responding to click event,

Tags: iphone

I am working on the table view and do customization for `tableFooterView`.What I am doing is :

ClassA.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    FooterViewController    *footerView     =   [[FooterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooterViewController" bundle:nil];


    // Add selector of Class A to checkOutButton
    [footerView.checkOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCheckOut) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.shoppingListTable.tableFooterView.backgroundColor  =   [UIColor clearColor];
    self.shoppingListTable.tableFooterView  =   footerView.view;
}

- (void)goToCheckOut {
    NSLog(@"this is a response from a button");
}
```

FootViewController.h

```
@interface FooterViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *amount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkOutButton;
@end
```

The outlet are also connected to the xib files as well

However, when I click on the button, it does not respond at all and the log shows nothing....

What I am doing wrong at here. Please help if you have any ideas about this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[footerView.checkOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCheckOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I know what I am doing wrong here. First, I made a change like you said and then I had to swap the lines `addTarget` after assigning `footerView.view` to `self.shoppingListTable.tableFooterView`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you set a wrong `forControlEvents` parameter. For invoking a method by pressing a button you need to use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

So change your this line `[footerView.checkOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCheckOut) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];`

**to**

`[footerView.checkOutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCheckOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Please check the control events reference : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html